# Wrong values while aspect calculation

Tags: qgis, aspect

Trying to calculate aspect for south direction of my DEM. In [this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/terrain_analysis.html) manual it is explained how to do it for nothern direction. But when I'm trying to use the expression of this type for southern:

```
"Aspect@1" >= 135 OR "Aspect@1" <= 225
```

I'm getting mistake. Both white and black values of resulting raster = 1.[image]

How to change expression to get raster which will give meunderstanding of slopes facing south?
I'm working in QGIS 3.10.4, CRS - Pulkovo 1942 / Gauss-Kruger zone 11.

Comment: What is your expected output? 1 for south 0 for north?

Comment: I'm expecting to get 1 for slopes facing south and 0 for the rest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have created the aspect raster using for example: Raster terrain analysis - Aspect.

Then your expression will always evaluate to True/1 since all aspect values are between 0-360 and will either be `>= 135` or `<= 225`

See: [To select the range of values using Raster calculator in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149985/to-select-the-range-of-values-using-raster-calculator-in-qgis)

I'm using 90-270 degrees for south:

```
(("aspect@1"<=90) AND ("aspect@1">=270))*0 + (("aspect@1">90) AND ("aspect@1"<270))*1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Bera! I do understand what your expression means, but I'm still getting an error. "An error occured while performing the calculation"...

Comment: I had to save the aspect raster to disk (as a tif file), did not work with a temporary aspect raster. You are using a temp aspect raster?

Comment: I've changed CRS to WGS 84 / UTM zone 41N, saved aspect raster to disk and finally got what I expected! Thank you so much! This trick took 5 hours out of my life...